# How can I convert this series to an equation: $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{2^{n}}{(2n)!\cdot2^{n}}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

At the beginning this wasn't a series, there were just fractions added with fractions... I converted this to a series already and I know it's correct because I put some values in to test. Here it is as series:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{2^{n}}{(2n)!\cdot2^{n}} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2n)!}$$

Now I'd like to know how can we change this series to an equation? Please tell me step by step if you can, I don't want know the direct solution. I want know how I can convert it.

Comment: A (convergent) series is a number. An *equation* is something like $A(x)=B(x)$. What does it mean to *convert a number into an equation*?

Comment: If you are looking for a universal method for finding the closed form of a series, if existing, you are looking for the holy grail. But in this particular case, the given series is a well-known Taylor series evaluated at $x=1$. The core of the technique lies in recognizing that.

Comment: Like this: $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{2^{n}}{(2n)!\cdot2^{n}} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2n)!}=\cosh 1 = \frac{e^1+e^{-1}}{2} = \frac{e^2+1}{2e}$$
This is the solution but I'd like to know HOW we get to this solution. For further tasks like this, I cannot keep all the well known series in my mind, there will be too many. There is really no formula for this? Very frustrating if not.

Comment: $$\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}$$ is the Taylor series of an entire, even function that fulfills $f''(x)=f(x)$ and $f(0)=1$. Aka $\cosh(x)=\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{2}$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio That's the idea I was about to suggest, but if you start with $x^n$ instead of $x^{2n}$, it won't be as easy. So you have to guess $2n$ is better to remove a factor from the denominator when differentiating. But in more complicated cases, it's pretty hopeless. Holy grail, exactly :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is exactly $\cosh(1)$:

$$\cosh(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}$$

Comment: I know that but it doesn't help me at all. I was asking for a method to convert it.

Comment: @klbrtree well what do you mean exactly

Comment: I want know a way to change this series to an equation without knowing that it equals $cos h$. You both gave me the solution but I want know why / how we get to this solution.

Comment: well $\cosh(x)$ *is* exactly the Taylor series i've posted. This is one way you can define $\cosh(x)$ .

Comment: What if I don't know this is $\cos h(x)$? Let's say I sit in an exam with this task. There is no other way?There must be..

Comment: which series do you actually know? usually it's not simple to determine the value of a series

Comment: $e^{x}$ and thats it :P

Comment: well actually this can be expressed in terms of $e^x$, since $\cosh(x) = \frac 1 2 \left(e^x + e^{-x}\right)$. But it's way easier to know $\cosh(x)$ right upfront.

Comment: @klbrtree: it is a standard exercise, an a quite simple one, too. Taylor series are a great tool in calculus, and students have to acquire confidence in using them. What a professor should do for letting you achieve this task? Don't call him/her stupid - my own ignorance is *nobody's fault but mine*.

Answer (score 2):

Hint
$$\cosh x=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }{\frac {x^{2n}}{(2n)!}}$$
let $x=1$

Comment: What if I don't know about $\cosh x$? There is no formula that converts a series to an equation?

Comment: you cannot convert it If you don't know about the $\cosh x$

Comment: Wow so this task cannot be solved without keeping the solution in mind, awesome task!

Comment: @klbrtree You seem to be missing the rather important point big time: it is *not* that you "have to know the solution", or "have it in mind" . First, you have to know *a power series* converges at all in some interval, then  you can name it somehow. And yes: you must know some stuff to attack things like this one, a non-elementary exercise in a non-elementary, though rather basic, subject. That's how people learns things.